# Обработка нажатия клавиш в цикле

Tags: winapi, многопоточность, visual-studio, c++

В течение всего цикла необходимо проверять была ли нажата определенная клавиша, но так как в коде необходима задержка, то чтобы клавиша считалась, необходимо, чтобы она была зажата во время начала цикла. Вопрос: можно ли средствами C++, WinAPI реализовать это без еще одного потока. Если нельзя, то как реализовать многопоточность.

```
while(1){
    if(GetKeyState(VK_RETURN) & 0x8000){
        ...
    }
    if(GetKeyState(VK_UP) & 0x8000){
        ...
    }
    if(GetKeyState(VK_DOWN) & 0x8000){
        ...
    }
    if(GetKeyState(VK_LEFT) & 0x8000){
        ...
    }
    if(GetKeyState(VK_RIGHT) & 0x8000){
        ...
    }
    ...
    Sleep(1000);
    ...
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: А почему просто не просить пользователя ввести команду в начале цикла?

Comment: Потому что должна быть возможность ввести клавишу в любой момент цикла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не должны изобретать велосипед. Просто создайте окно стандартным способом, и в вашей WindowProc реагируйте на `WM_KEYDOWN`/`WM_KEYUP`.

Comment: давно это было)

Comment: @proCion: Это да, но не оставлять же вопрос без ответа? :) Лучше поздно, чем никогда!

Answer (score 0):

Не могу сейчас точно ответить на вопрос, но если я не ошибаюсь в WinAPI есть функция работы со стеком сообщений системы. Так вот в этот самый стек записываются все сообщения системы, в том числе и сообщение о нажатии клавиш. Тебе всего лишь следует обработать это сообщение при его возникновении и будет тебе счастье. GetMessage и PeekMessage - это обработка сообщений, думаю поиск дальше тебе поможет.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - MSDN про циклы сообщений.